# Convert INT to Date time in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one updated_time column in SQL database for which the data from source system are coming in Int format,ex.- 165022, 154914, 175147,where the first 2 digit refers to hours,next 2 digit to minutes & last 2 for seconds. I have to store them on data base in date time format,like - 16:50:22.

I am using this query -

```
declare @upd_time int =165022
```

`select CAST(STUFF(STUFF(@upd_time,5,0,':'),3,0,':') AS time)`

This works fine but when I have data in 5 digit,like - 83714,which should be transformed into 08:37:14,it fails.
I tried to pad the data with leading zeros with the below query -

```
select Right('000000'+ convert(varchar,83714),6) as Time_Upd
```

But still the **STUFF** function ignores the zero & converts to 83:71:4 which can't be used in **CAST**. Any workaround for this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Think about the problem as a maths problem rather than a string one. We can use integer division and modulus to find the right values to add onto a base time:

```
declare @upd_time int = 83714

select  DATEADD(hour,@upd_time / 10000,
        DATEADD(minute,(@upd_time / 100) % 100,
        DATEADD(second,@Upd_time % 100,'00:00:00')))
```

Produces a `datetime` value of `1900-01-01 08:37:14.000` (which can then be cast to `time` if required)

Answer (score 1):

It is because your variable upd_time is an int variable. Below code should do the job for you:

```
declare @upd_time int =12345 
declare @new_upd_time varchar(6)
set @new_upd_time = right('000000' + cast(@upd_time as varchar(6)), 6)
declare @finaltime nvarchar(8)
set @finaltime = left(@new_upd_time,2) + ':' + left(right(@new_upd_time,4),2) +':'+right(@new_upd_time,2)
select @finaltime
```